# Issues with Apache Camel Route for Form Data Upload without Spring Boot

Tags: forms, routes, apache-camel, form-data

I'm currently working on an Apache Camel project without Spring Boot, and I'm facing challenges with creating a route that handles form data. I've encountered a JsonParseException issue that I'm struggling to resolve.

Problem:

I'm trying to create a Camel route that receives form data and uploads it to a downstream service. However, I'm encountering the following error:

> 2023-12-11T15:51:33,380 ERROR [XNIO-1 task-6] : Failed delivery for (MessageId: AFFA0D62E217B39-0000000000000002 on ExchangeId: AFFA0D62E217B39-0000000000000002). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value.

Class:

```
public class PageUpload extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    String URL = "some link";

    restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");

    rest("/pageUpload")
            .post()
            .description("IG API to upload file in ImageRight")
            .id("pageUpload")
            .consumes("multipart/form-data")
            .type(IRPageUploadRequestPayload.class)
            .produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .route()
            .to(PAGE_UPLOAD)
            .endRest();

    from(PAGE_UPLOAD)
            .routeId(this.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .unmarshall().mimeMultipart()
            .process(new TokenProcessor()) // token processor for bearer token gen
            .toD(URL + BRIDGE_ENDPOINT)
            .log("Azure Response Body: ${body}")
            .end();
}
}
```

Payload Class (IRPageUploadRequestPayload):

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class IRPageUploadRequestPayload {
@JsonProperty("DocumentType")
private String DocumentType;
@JsonProperty("FileNumber")
private String FileNumber;
@JsonProperty("PolicyEffectiveDate")
private String PolicyEffectiveDate;
@JsonProperty("Content")
private File Content;
@JsonProperty("Description")
private String Description;
@JsonProperty("UserId")
private String UserId;
@JsonProperty("Username")
private String Username;
}
```

Question:

What could be causing the JsonParseException error in this scenario, and how can I ensure that my Apache Camel route correctly handles form data without attempting to parse it as JSON?

Additional Information:

I'm trying to consume the route from Swagger.
I've verified that the Content-Type header is set to multipart/form-data.
I've included the TokenProcessor for bearer token generation.
I appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, when you use `.produces(APPLICATION_JSON)` you get JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off binding mode

> .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)

to

> .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)

Comment: you're genius. It worked. Thanks a lot. have good one